# How to center search bar in jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following html: (jsfiddle included at bottom):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="jumbotron">
      <!--Search Bar-->
    <form class="form-inline" method = "GET" action = "{% url 'search' %}" >
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="query"  type="text" placeholder="Zip Code or City/Town">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success  my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Find Jobs</button>
    </form>
  <p class="lead">The only job site on the web dedicated to positions that don't require a degree
      (IOS and Android app coming soon!)</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p class="lead">
    <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-md learn_more_buttons" href="{% url 'business_owners_info' %}" role="button">Business Owner's Learn More</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md learn_more_buttons" href="{% url 'job_seekers_info' %}" role="button">Job Seekers Learn More</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1d02twy/2/

How do I center the search bar and button in the jumbotron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've checked your code you are using `Bootstrap` so you can add `bootstrap` default classes like:

Add `text-center` class to main `div` class and `justify-content-center` class to form tag.

Check this: [http://jsfiddle.net/x1d02twy/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/x1d02twy/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `justify-content-center` class to your form

http://jsfiddle.net/x1d02twy/6/

Answer (score 0):

Add div outside elements you want to center and then apply `margin: 0 auto;` to center that wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/x1d02twy/8/